# How to cling a svg text to svg circle?

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, css-animations

In short i want that no matter where the circle move, a text will be with him.

I have a code similiar to this:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
<g>
<circle cx="50%" cy="6%" r="7%" [ngStyle]="{'fill': circlerColor, 'transform': 'rotate(' + circleDegrees + 'deg)', 'transform-origin': 'center center', 'transition': 'transform 0.5s'}"></circle>

<text cx="50%" cy="6%" r="7%" style="z-index: 100; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;" [ngStyle]="{'fill': circlerColor, 'transform': 'rotate(' + circleDegrees + 'deg)', 'transform-origin': 'center center', 'transition': 'transform 0.5s'}"></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

From the code you see that the circle move like a clock, 360 degrees.
Now, this code realy "cling" the text to the circle, but rotated! For example when its on 180 degrees, the text is "up side down".
I want some how, from the text to stay horizonal, "cling" but horizontally.

Thanks in ahead!

Comment: 1. Use a viewBox attribute instead of width and height for the svg element. 2.  Use a path instead of a circle. For a circle with cx="500" cy="80" r="70" you can use this d attribute : `M570,80A70,70 0 0 1 430,80 A70,70 0 0 1 570,80`. 3. Read about [text on a path in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) . 4. Do not rotate the circle, use [startOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/startOffset) instead. 5. z-index is meaningless in SVG

Comment: @enxaneta thank you for your feedback. I changed every thing you say, but it doesnt realy work. Instead of circle i have path, so the property startoffset applied on textPath will travel around the circle-path, so how does it help? I mean, the text isnt horizontally. If i put long string, the text will take a shape of a circle, not horizonal line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution i ended with is like my code in my question.

Must be a 'g' tag, which wrap the text and the circle.
Now, you dont move the circle alone with transform: rotate, translate etc, all this operation must be on the whole group, i mean on the 'g' tag.

I had a specific problem, that even if the rotation will be inside the 'g' tag, the text wont be horizontally.
The solution is simple, the 'g' is the "parent", the text inside is the "child". So rotate the parent for ex' 180 degrees, and rotate the child - 180 degrees.

Read more about "move element in a circular path" :

https://usefulangle.com/post/32/moving-an-element-in-circular-path-with-css